# How can I beat the Compulsive Gambler in Gem Minder 2?

Tags: android, gem-miner-2

In Gem Minder 2, in MEDIUM complexity Expedition "Sale!", one of the ancillary star goals is to "Beat the Compulsive Gambler".

The Gambler takes gold... and keeps winning. So far, I lost 7 gold nuggets in a row (several times) so clearly it's NOT random.

Should I simply keep searching for more Gold Nuggets and the logic for the win is 'Feed the gambler at least N nuggets first'?

If so, does it matter if I save between gambling (so I can sell the rest of my gems between saves)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buy four-leaf clover. The first attempt succeded.